# Using has_many through inside a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Evaluation with a has_many with model Tag through evaluation_tags

I need to add this relationship in this Module, but i don't know how can i do this

```
class Evaluation < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :teacher
    belongs_to :school
    belongs_to :subject

    has_many :evaluation_tags
    has_many :tags, through: :evaluation_tags

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :evaluation_tags

    validates :teacher_id, presence: true
    validates :subject_id, presence: true
    validates :school_id, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :rating, presence: true
end

module Wizard
  module Evaluation
    STEPS = %w(step1 step2 step3).freeze

    class Base
      include ActiveModel::Model
      attr_accessor :evaluation

      delegate *::Evaluation.attribute_names.map { |attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :evaluation

      def initialize(evaluation_attributes)
        @evaluation = ::Evaluation.new(evaluation_attributes)
      end
    end

    class Step1 < Base
      validates :teacher_id, presence: true
    end

    class Step2 < Step1
      validates :subject_id, presence: true
    end

    class Step3 < Step2
      validates :school, presence: true
      validates :user, presence: true
      validates :rating, presence: true
    end
  end
end
```

When i access the step3 page, this error appears

undefined method `tag_ids' for #

Can anyone help me?

Comment: why do not you just include the module into Evaluation?

Comment: Can you show me, please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), like this:

```
module Wizard
  module Evaluation
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      has_many :tags, through: :evaluation_tags
    end
  end
end
```

then your class need to include it:

```
class Evaluation
  include Wizard::Evaluation
end
```

Comment: Thank you, i need to include "include Wizard::Evaluation" inside the model?

Comment: The error "undefined method `tag_ids' for #<Wizard::Evaluation::Step3:0x00007f657424dca0>" continues